# Method from javascript object is always undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, object, prototype

I'm trying to work with Imsomnia plugin for cordova (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin), inside a Quasar Framework project for android.

Using `console.log(window.plugins.insomnia)`, i can see two methods inside `__proto__`:

```
__proto__:
allowSleepAgain: ƒ (successCallback, errorCallback)
keepAwake: ƒ (successCallback, errorCallback)
```

I need to call `window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()`, but it is always `undefined`. What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is exact error you are getting?

Comment: Did you wait for `deviceready` event

Comment: @dhaker window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake() is undefined

Comment: @dhaker yes, this code is inside deviceready